Plotting data with missing points in Excel
Consider a spreadsheet for monitoring blood pressure.  It has three columns:  date, systolic pressure, and diastolic pressure.  Each day, a new row is added.  There's also a "Line with Markers" chart that plots the two measurements over time.
If I fail to record a measurement on a given day, the chart does the intuitive thing:  The X axis steps consistently through time, but there are no markers on the days there are no measurements.



Date
Sys
Dia
Comment




4/1/2024
127
69



4/2/2024
118
72






no measurement, no problem


4/4/2024
122
73




Suppose, though, I fail to record just one of the measurements.  On a particular row I have the date and the systolic pressure but a blank cell for the diastolic pressure.  The chart will show the diastolic pressure dropping to 0 on that day.



Date
Sys
Dia
Comment




4/1/2024
127
69



4/2/2024
118
72



4/3/2024
120

Chart shows missing Dia as 0


4/4/2024
122
73




How do I get the chart to omit individual missing values rather than treating them as zero?

I was asked to include a picture:


Please add a picture of your chart doing this.

Right click on the chart and choose "Select Data" from the popup menu
In the resulting dialog box, choose "Gaps" from the drop down menu near the bottom


Accepted, because clearly that should be the right answer.  But there must be a bug in the version I'm using.  "Gaps" was already selected.  The chart does leave a gap when there's no date and no measurement.  But if there is a date and no measurement, it still plots it as though the measurement is 0.

I'm using Microsoft® Excel® 2019 MSO (Version 2403 Build 16.0.17425.20176) 64-bit.
